# How to fix psycopg2.InterfaceError: connection already closed?

Tags: python, postgresql

I had a problem in my application written in flask, there was a connection to the database and everything was working correctly, but I lost access to the table by setting sql queries through python or through pgadmin, i.e. no errors were generated, but just infinite loading (with any queries).

Running the query "select * from pg_stat_activity;" I saw that some sessions are idle in transaction.

Then I decided to execute the following query

```
SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pid)
FROM pg_stat_activity 
WHERE datname = 'dbname'
  AND pid <> pg_backend_pid()
  AND state = 'idle in transaction' 
  AND state_change < current_timestamp - INTERVAL '5' MINUTE;
```

I can now run queries from pgadmin/python and generally connect to this table, but when I open my application I get this error.

**psycopg2.InterfaceError: connection already closed**

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2213, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2193, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2190, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1486, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1484, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1469, in dispatch_request
return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/T2app/./app.py", line 27, in index
cur = conn.cursor()
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
psycopg2.InterfaceError: connection already closed
```

My python code looks like this (I understand that it is not implemented in the best way, but I have not been able to get it to work by performing the connection to the database and the query itself in separate objects or functions), it would be great if someone could tell me how to implement it better.

```
def index():
    # database connection
    with psycopg2.connect(**params) as conn:
        # creating a cursor object to run PostgreSQL commands on the database
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM fact_table;") 
        rows = cur.fetchall()
        cur.close()
    
    If request.method == "POST":
        With psycopg2.connect(**params) as conn:
            # creating a cursor object to run PostgreSQL commands on the database
            cur = conn.cursor()
            cur.execute("SELECT {} FROM fact_table WHERE year = ANY(%s) AND indicators = ANY(%s) AND station_name = ANY(%s);"
                        .format(",".join(["{\"{}\""".format(c) for c in columns])),(selected_years, selected_indicators, selected_stations)))
            # To access the generated fetch we use cur.fetchall()
            rows = cur.fetchall()
            cur.close()
```

Can you please advise me on how I can fix this?

Comment: Which `cur = conn.cursor()` results in the error? The first or the second one?

Comment: I understand that this error will disappear if I restart the application. (I think it is due to manual killing of idle in transaction sql query). But the problem will remain in the future, I think that my code related to the database is not correct.
The error cur = conn.cursor() occurs in the first case

Comment: From docs [psycopg2 connection](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/connection.html): *Note that the connection is not closed by the context and it can be used for several contexts*. Read the information at the link. The quick hint close the connections.